# CSS Specificity is not following the formula

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have the following code

```
<style type="text/css">
    .el3 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
    .el1, .el3 { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; }
    .el1, .el2, .el3 { font: Helvetica; }
</style>

<div class="el3">Text</div>
```

When I load up my browser and inspect the element with class `el3` I find that the font-family is `Tahoma, sans-serif`.

I know that I didn't add the classes `.el1` and `.el2` to my HTML, but I still expected the result to be `Helvetica`. When I inspect the element, that ruling is crossed out.

There are two reasons why the font should be Helvetica.

The specificity formula is as follows

1. Add 1 point if the style is inline
2. Add 1 point for every id selector in the query
3. Add 1 point for every class, attribute or pseudo class selector
4. Add 1 point for every element or pseudo element

The score is typically measured in bracket notation. In my example, the three rules would be given these three specificity scores

```
.el1                    => {0,0,1,0}
.el1,.el2               => {0,0,2,0}
.el1, .el2, .el3        => {0,0,3,0}
```

It shouldn't make a difference whether `.el1` and `.el2` are defined. 3 class selectors should have higher precedence than 2 class selectors.

The second reason is that even if they both had the same precedence, the tiebreaker would go to rule 3 because it appears last.

It also can't possibly be because for the first two rules I used the `font-family` property and for the last one I used `font`.

Based on the precedence rules, the font should clearly be `Helvetica`.

Comment: Have you checked http://specificity.keegan.st ?

Comment: OK, my bad. My calculations were off. They should all have a specificity of `{0,0,1,0}` however the answer should still by `Helvetica` since it was declared last

Comment: It looks like shorthand properties don't override specific properties, as in this case, if I change the last rule to ` .el1, .el2, .el3 { font-family: Helvetica; }`, it uses Helvetica. So it's not a specificity issue, it's a property issue. Trying to see if this is stated in any of the docs.

Comment: You are correct. I tried with font-family and got Helvetica, but with just font, I get Tahoma, sans-serif. This is really strange. Hopefully someone can explain this

Comment: I think I see the issue. `font` as a shorthand property has the syntax : `<'font-style'> | <'font-variant'> | <'font-weight'> | <'font-size'> | <'line-height'> | <'font-family'>`, and your use of it is not being picked up as applying to the `font-family`, so it's using the earlier rule to avoid resetting the `font-family` to default.

Comment: If you change all three rules to use `font:`, none are applied, so I think it's treating the `font:` property as invalid. But if I change them all to `font` and start each rule with `1em` followed by the font-family, it uses the last rule and sets the font-family to Helvetica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't specificity, it's validity. With the given rules:

```
.el3 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el3 { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el2, .el3 { font: Helvetica; }
```

The last one isn't applied because it's treated as invalid. You can confirm by testing:

```
.el3 { font: Arial, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el3 { font: Tahoma, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el2, .el3 { font: Helvetica; }
```

Where none of the font-families are applied. This seems to be related to how shorthand properties (like `font`) are validated. If I change the second set of test rules to:

```
.el3 { font: 1em Arial, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el3 { font: 1em Tahoma, sans-serif; }
.el1, .el2, .el3 { font: 1em Helvetica; }
```

Then the last rule gets applied. This seems contrary to the [CSS spec on shorthand properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#shorthand) which actually warn that using a shorthand without specifying all properties will result in the property being treated as set to the initial value for the property:

> When values are omitted from a shorthand form, unless otherwise
>   defined, each “missing” sub-property is assigned its initial value.
>
> This means that a shorthand property declaration always sets all of
>   its sub-properties, even those that are not explicitly set. ***Carelessly
>   used***, this might result in inadvertently resetting some
>   sub-properties. ***Carefully used***, a shorthand can guarantee a “blank
>   slate” by resetting sub-properties inadvertently cascaded from other
>   sources. For example, writing background: green rather than
>   background-color: green ensures that the background color overrides
>   any earlier declarations that might have set the background to an
>   image with background-image.

But I think since the rule isn't being applied at all, the client (browser) is instead treating the shorthand property with only one single-property being set as invalid outright.

### Further Findings:

I'm not sure what their source is, but the [MDN doc on the font property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) does mention this issue explicitly:

> Note: There are a few caveats when using the CSS font shorthand. ***If
>   these conditions are not met, the property is invalid and is entirely
>   ignored.***
>
> - Except when using a keyword, ***it is mandatory to define the value of both the font-size and the font-family properties***.
> - Not all values of font-variant are allowed. Only the values defined in CSS 2.1 are allowed, that is normal and small-caps.
> - Though not directly settable by font, the values of font-stretch, font-size-adjust and font-kerning are also reset to their initial
>     values.
> - The order of the values is not completely free: font-style, font-variant and font-weight must be defined, if any, before the
>     font-size value. The line-height value must be defined immediately
>     after the font-size, preceded by a mandatory /. Finally the
>     font-family is mandatory and must be the last value defined (inherit
>     value does not work).

### Source from Spec:

If you look at the [`font` property specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand), it has the following:

> Value:    [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]?
>   <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption |
>   icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit

which for anyone who can sight-read EBNF (not me) can see means that the shorthand requires either (a keyword) or (font-size and font-family) to be set in order be considered valid. The grammar above looks kinda like:

```
[ 
    [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ] 
    ? 
    <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ] 
    ? 
    <'font-family'> 
] 
| caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit
```

Comment: The source is the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand) of course, where the value is defined as  `[ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit`. Note that there is no question mark after `<'font-size'>` and `<'font-family'>` indicating that they are not optional within the first group (i.e. before the first `|`)

Comment: @Alohci - Just put that together myself. If you know of a good lex parser that would make the Value syntax more human-readable / checkable, I'll add it to the answer, as it would be helpful for testing other shorthand properties, I'm sure.